# MongoDB map a JSON response into a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
        const FoundWarning = db.collection('warning').find({UserID: Warned.user.id, guildID: message.guild.id}).toArray(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        })
```

I was trying to find more than one collection using MongoDB,
I don't quite know how to map it and turn it into a String as there are multiple responses and not just one JSON document to use so I would have to map through them,

Can someone explain how I can turn this Data to chunks that I can use like a string, an object or an array?

I suppose I have to parse it and map it first, correct me if I'm wrong
But I don't think I know how to do that

Here is the photo of the current result that I have
[image]

I wanted to (for example) get the "Reason" part of it in a string alone and send each "Reason" along side with the "UserName" and send it as a message on discord using discord.js so like loop through them for example

Edit: i forgot to mention that "Warned" is

```
let Warned = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Sorry if I'm not good at explaining, I would appreciate edits if you understand what's the issue that I'm facing

Comment: i used this to be able to do that part of code https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/ 
i hope this helps explaining what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/jlgctv/mongodb_find_items_in_collections_and_put_them/gap2qzv?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

You can simply access the `Reason` property of an object. What you are facing is an array of objects and each object inside the array contains a `Reason` property. You can either access one object, for example, `results[0]` and then access the `Reason` property like this `results[0].Reason` or you can store all the reasons inside an array like this:

```js
const reasons = results.map(result => result.Reason);
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer! i just have a small question, someone on reddit said that this will also work 

results.map(user => { return user.Reason; });

Is it the same thing? or is the one you sent me an easier way?

Comment: It's the same thing